# Unknown reporting services password

Tags: windows, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with Reporting Services credentials ( SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard on Windows Server 2008 R2).

I have to create few new reports, but when i'm trying to connect to `http://SERVERNAME:80/ReportServer_DB` i am asked for credentials.

In Reporting Services Configuration Manager -> Database -> Current Report Server Database Credential i have:

```
Credential: Service Account
Login: DOMAIN\USER
Password: **************
```

I cannot change the password, because of the third party software using it already. Is there a way to recover (**NOT RESET**) the user password ? or maybe is there a way to add another account to access reporting services ? or maybe to set up 2nd instance of the reporting services ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE (and other browsers, including Chrome) ask for credentials based on the Internet Options on the environment where you are trying to connect:

[image]

Set the security to **Automatic logon with current user name and password** and the browser will pass your Windows credentials on automatically, i.e. no popup.

Will this allow you to get to the Report Server? It depends on what privileges your user account has been assigned on the Report Server.

By default, the **BUILTIN\Administrators** group will have the **Content Manager** role (i.e. full report management privileges) - you will need to either be in this group (i.e. an Administrator on the SSRS server) or have been assigned this privilege either directly to your user or implicitly through a group.

If you don't have access, the first thing to try is log on to the server as an Administrator and try connecting to **Report Manager** from there. I note that you are trying to connect to the **Report Server** website, but the **Report Manager** website will typically used for administration tasks.

You'll note I haven't mentioned **Current Report Server Database Credential** - this is not anything to do with your issue; it is simply used by the SSRS service user to connect to the underlying **reportserver** database - it is used by the service for creating/retrieving report/server metadata and will have no effect on users trying to connect to the **Report Manager** website through a browser or other method, which is controlled by the privileges set at the **Report Manager** level.